# Counting occurrences of string and `groupby` categorical variable in `pandas`

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, count, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe in `Pandas` that has categorical information as well as free text data.
I would like to `count` the number of times a specific string occurs in the free text data and `groupby` each categorical variable.

Some of the strategies I have been using are as follows, but does not provide me with my desired result.
What can I modify to achieve final desired result?

```
country freeText
USA yes
China   no
USA yes
Brazil  no
Brazil  no
China   no

df[df['freeText']=='no'].groupby('country').count()
df.groupby('country')['freeText'].str.contains('no').sum()
```

Desired result

```
USA 0
China   2
Brazil  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Compare the *text* and create the booleans, then do a `groupby.sum` -

```
df.freeText.eq('no').groupby(df.country).sum()

#country
#Brazil    2.0
#China     2.0
#USA       0.0
#Name: freeText, dtype: float64
```

Or the common `groupby.agg/apply` syntax:

```
df.groupby('country').freeText.agg(lambda g: g.eq('no').sum())

#country
#Brazil    2
#China     2
#USA       0
#Name: freeText, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pd.get_dummies` to get all at once (yes/no)

```
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['freeText']).groupby('country').sum()

        No  Yes
country     
Brazil  2   0
China   2   0
USA     0   2
```